# Rich Snippet last breadcrumb is not appearing in search result

Tags: seo, schema.org, rich-snippets

I am struggling with rich snippet for breadcrumbs and how these appear in the Google SERP

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs colored-links" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="https://www.example.com/" itemid="https://www.example.com/"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
</liexample
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="https://www.example.com/collections" itemid="https://www.example.com/collections"><span itemprop="name">Collections</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2">
</li>
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" itemid="https://www.example.com/collections/item3" ><span itemprop="name">Item3</span></span>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="3">
</li>
```

The code passes the Google Data Structure test. In the Google Search Result Page I do see a rich snippet for my website when a breadcrumb is on that particular page

I see this https://www.example.com > [Collections](http://#)

I am trying to get this

but it would be https://www.example.com > [Collections](http://#) > [Item3](http://#)

I have tried adding

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" itemid="https://www.example.com/collections/item3" typeof="WebPage" resource="https://www.example.com/collections/item3"><span itemprop="name">Item3</span>
```

Can it be avoided that the last breadcrumb is a link on the webpage?
Or is the only way to make it a link with similar code as to how content="1" and content="2" are done
edit: I just tried making the last breadcrumb a link and with search console updated the SERP, but it still does not show item3

the solution I am looking for should not be JSON-LD

Comment: Is this the breadcrumb trail for the item3 page. It does not make sense for Google to include the current page in the breadcrumb. Just like it avoids adding the home page.

Comment: What is the current page that has the `BreadcrumbList` you posted?

Comment: When searching for Item 3 I am trying to achieve this in the rich snippet of google search result page

https://www.example.com > Collections

I am trying to get this: 

https://www.example.com > Collections > Item3

On the page it is not linked, maybe hence it does not show up as a link in the SERP

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to see the last member of the breadcrumb as visible part of it, consider to add a real href link to its markup, like the second member already has. Like this:

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs colored-links" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="https://www.example.com/" itemid="https://www.example.com/"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
</li>
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="https://www.example.com/collections" itemid="https://www.example.com/collections"><span itemprop="name">Collections</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2">
</li>
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="https://www.example.com/collections/item3" itemid="https://www.example.com/collections/item3" ><span itemprop="name">Item3</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="3">
</li>
</ul>
```